# Print directory where file is saved with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how could do print the path directory of my file saved with python.
For ad example, i start with idle3 (Fedora 24), i save the IDLE code on: /home/jetson/Desktop/Python/Programs and in the code is written:

```
f = open("Hello.txt","w")
f.write("This is a test","\n")
f.close()
```

My question is: after f.close i would print the directory grabbed with

```
import sys.os 

print("The file is saved in ",direcotrysaved)
```

It's possible?

Comment: @SSNR That gives the path to current `.py` file, which does not have to be where `open` will open the file.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the relative path to absolute path:

```
path = os.path.abspath(filename)
```

Then take just the directory from the absolute path:

```
directory = os.path.dirname(path)
```

That will work regardless of what `filename` is. It could by just a filename, a relative path or absolute path.

See [os.path documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for other useful functions.

Answer (score 0):

If no path is given then the file is opened in the current working directory. This is returned by `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.getcwd()` for getting the current working directory:

```
import os

os.getcwd()
```

Otherwise, you could also specify the full path for the file when opening it, e.g.

```
f.open('/path/to/the/folder/Hello.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using f.name provides the file name if you didn't supply it as a separate variable.
Using `os.path.abspath()` provides the full file name including it's directory path i.e. in this case "/home/rolf/def"
Using `os.path.dirname()` strips the file name from the path, as that you already know.

```
>>> import os
>>> f=open('xxxx.txt','w')
>>> f.close()
>>> print(f.name,'Stored in', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(f.name)))

xxxx.txt Stored in /home/rolf/def
```